# Debug and release libraries and their executable program

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos

Just very curious with the following question: if a Debug executable program invokes a Release third library, what would happen? Will the program run without any crash? Then, how about a Release executable program invoke a Debug third library?   Will different platforms (windows, linux and mac) perform the same in either situation? Here I limit the programming language to c and c++.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing binaries with/without debug information on Windows (VS, mingw) and Linux (gcc)
is no problem. However, i can´t say for Mac or other compilers for sure
(but probably there is no difference)

Answer (score 0):

For the question, Will the program run without any crash when debug executable?

Yes, the debugger allocates more on the stack, so the program less likely to overwrite something important.